# Number of blocks in rational canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking at an example that says a 12x12 matrix $M$ has minimal polynomial $m(x)=(x^2+1)^3$ and characteristic polynomial $c(x)=(x^2+1)^6$. It says the number of blocks will be $$\frac{dim(null(M^2+I))}{deg(x^2+1)}.$$ Where does this come from? Is there a general way for determining the number of blocks? My textbook (Hoffman and Kunze, which is not where this example comes from) doesn't seem to say anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, [Hoffman and Kunze](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit) prove the general formula in Theorem 4 starting on page 237.